# 401 Error in React and django-rest-framework app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, django, django-rest-framework

First of all I got this useState which takes data from input:

```
const Checkout = ({cart, totalPrice, code}) => {
    const [values, setValues] = useState({
        email: '',
        city:'',
        adress:'',
        postalCode:'',
        phone:'',
        firstName:'',
        lastName:'',
        message:'',
        price: totalPrice,
        code: code,
        shipmentFee:0,
        shipmentMethod:'',
        lockerId:'',
        cart:cart,
    });
```

Then I submit it with `generateOrder(values)` function:

```
export const generateOrder = (order) => {
    return fetch(`${url}/orders/generate-bank-transfer-order/`,{
        method:"POST",
        body:order
    })
    .then((response) => {
        return response.json();
    })
    .catch((error) => console.log(error))
};
```

It points to this url in urls.py: `path('generate-bank-transfer-order/',generate_bank_transfer_order, name="generate-bank-transfer")`

And this is a view I use, for now I just want it to return submited data so I can test if it works:

```
@csrf_exempt
def generate_bank_transfer_order(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        body = request.body
    return JsonResponse({"test":body})
```

All I get is `401 Unauthorized` and I have no idea how to fix it. Any ideas?

Comment: Can u give us the details of `DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES` from settings.py?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the default authentication class in settings like :

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
    ]
}
```

First import

```
from rest_framework.permissions import AllowAny
```

then modify your function to

```
@api_view(['POST'])
@permission_classes([AllowAny])
def generate_bank_transfer_order(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        body = request.body
    return JsonResponse({"test":body})
```

> [For More Details](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/#allowany)
>
> The AllowAny permission class will allow unrestricted access,
> regardless of if the request was authenticated or unauthenticated.
>
> This permission is not strictly required, since you can achieve the
> same result by using an empty list or tuple for the permissions
> setting, but you may find it useful to specify this class because it
> makes the intention explicit.